# Integrating GPU Telemetry into Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, nvidia

https://docs.nvidia.com/datacenter/cloud-native/kubernetes/dcgme2e.html

helm install \

> --generate-name 
> gpu-helm-charts/dcgm-exporter

Error: unable to build kubernetes objects from release manifest: unable to recognize "": no matches for kind "ServiceMonitor" in version "monitoring.coreos.com/v1"

I using helm version: 3.5.2
Kubernetes Cluster:   1.19.5

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently your **Custom Resource Definition** creation has finished successfully but its API was not yet available when the installation proceeded with creation of the `ServiceMonitor` **Custom Resource**. Running `helm install ...` command once again should help.